# What could be a corresponding input to this output?

Tags: c, memory, printf, exploit, format-specifiers

Consider the following code:

```
void main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char j[22] = "This is a long string", k[3];
    scanf("%2s", k);
    sprintf(j, k);
    for (; i < 21; printf("%c", j[i++]));
}
```

It is given that the output is:

> U%ae'$ffq` ong string

What could be the input?

So I think it should be something like `%d` or `%x`. So it executes: `sprintf(j, "%x");` but there's no corresponding variable to this format.

1. What does the function do in this case? It seems like an address
2. What could be the input? Is it `%x` or something else?

Comment: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: @SouravGhosh Your comment is not necessarily correct, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518).

Comment: If your `scanf()` scans in any `sprintf()`-conversion-specifiers, the behavior is undefined, as the `sprintf()` will not have the corresponding arguments.

Comment: @Lundin technically, yes, but for vast majority of the cases, it will be applicable (normal, hosted env). For freestanding env, there's no restriction, at all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be told for *sure*, but it looks evident that the input for `k` is essentially *some form of a* format specifier. It can be *any* of the many.

After that, due to the missing argument to that format specifier, `sprintf()` is invoking undefined behaviour, as stated in `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> [..] If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined. [...]

To avoid this kind of error, do not pass a user input as the format string to the `printf()` family. Use a safer from, like

```
  printf("fixed format string with format specifiers %s %d and all", arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Consider: `sprintf(j, "%d");` - What would it print exactly?

Comment: @RonErikson  due to missing argument, it is UB, and the output is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf(j, k);` should be `sprintf(j, "%s", k);` - please check `sprintf` prototype.

Comment: You're very right, but I think OP is asking about the format string injection kind of scenario.